# Sound issues after using headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, 17.04

I have just installed Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 on my Dell Vostro 5000 series. It all installed and worked fine.

The sound worked fine when I first used it. Then I plugged in my headphones. They worked fine for about 2 minutes. Then the audio stopped. I unplugged them and re plugged them a few times but the audio was completely gone. Needed to restart to fix. The headphones work fine in Windows 10, (previous OS).

Not sure where to start, I'm fairly new to linux, and know practically nothing about the way sound works.

Thanks in advance for any help
TBJ